# How to fit the content in a element when screen goes to the mobile view?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to fit the content inside the element so that it occupies most of the space. So I will provide a screenshot of the output, where you can see that the size of the content is smaller when compared to the actual size of the element. I tried using flex. I think the problem might be giving fixed height and width.

```css
 

.white{
            background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
            flex: 50%;
            display: flex;
            width: 720px;
            height: 600px;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        
    }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .flexed {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  }
  .white {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .btn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .heading {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .para {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="flexy">
    <div class="black">
      <div class="test">
        <img src="assets/no3_logo1.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="white">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="heading">Feature that is amazing.</p>
        <p class="para">Lo sectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi quasi dignissimos eos obcaecati aliquid dicta consequatur ipsa laudantium atque deserunt!</p>
        <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here I'm  providing the screenshot of the output.
Image-
[image]

Comment: Could you share your codes as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Voted to re-open, since the code's been added as requested; @Melroy: "*the content of the paragraph is not getting set properly in the mobile view*" - could you offer details? What do you mean by "*properly*," what should it look like, or do?

Comment: I updated to make a snippet of code BUT "I think the problem might be giving fixed height and width." I see nothing like what I would consider "fixed" in that regard in the CSS and this does not appear like the linked image really.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the codes in the images, but still, try this:

```
.text {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.para {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I tried adding but the content is still not taking the whole element.

Comment: Is it because i have assigned fixed values?Iike height and  width?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the output of your codes?